# Controller doesn't get parent data

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing a tutorial over angular 1.5 and I've gotten far into it and one of the sections seems broken concerning matching a current user to the author username. The class injects the User service and I think assumes I can inherit from a parent controller for the author but it comes up undefined. I tried injecting $scope then setting a variable to $scope.$parent.article (article is the object that has the author name in it) but this was still undefined. I checked the parent controller doing a console log on article and it does have the data that I am trying to get. Here is a link to my project if you want to look at the entire thing but I'll try to post just the relevant code below. https://github.com/RawleJuglal/flow_news_app/tree/front_end/src/js

Parent Controller (article.controller.js)

```
import marked from 'marked';

class ArticleCtrl {
  constructor(article, $sce, $rootScope) {
    'ngInject';

    this.article = article;
    console.log(this.article);
    //THIS IS CONSOLE LOG 
    //{title: "Juglal For StackOverflow", 
       slug: "juglal-for-stackoverflow-ba400n", 
       body: "<p> Need the goods</p>", 
       createdAt: "2017-04-25T14:51:42.131Z", 
       updatedAt: "2017-04-25T14:51:42.131Z",
       author:{
            bio:"I'm a MEAN stack developer. But if I don't find a job in Oklahoma soon, I'll be learning C++/Sharp."
            following:false
            image:"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/p/6/000/1e9/0e2/3cd7175.jpg"
            username:"RawleJuglal",....
      }

// Update the title of this page
 $rootScope.setPageTitle(this.article.title);

 this.article.body = $sce.trustAsHtml(marked(this.article.body, { sanitize: true }));

  }
}


export default ArticleCtrl;
```

Child Controller (article-actions.components.js)

```
class ArticleActionsCtrl {
  constructor(Articles, User, $state) {
    'ngInject';

    this._Articles = Articles;
    this._$state = $state;

//Code that causes the error because this.article.author.username is undefined
     if (User.current) {
       this.canModify = (User.current.username === this.article.author.username);
     } else {
       this.canModify = false;
     }
  }
}

let ArticleActions = {
  bindings: {
    article: '='
  },
  controller: ArticleActionsCtrl,
  templateUrl: 'article/article-actions.html'
};

export default ArticleActions;
```

HTML(article.html) //Just in case this the problem

```
<div class="article-page">
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 ng-bind="::$ctrl.article.title"></h1>
      <article-actions article="$ctrl.article"></article-actions>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container page">
    <div class="row article-content">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div>
          <div ng-bind-html="::$ctrl.article.body"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="tag-list">
          <li class="tag-default tag-pill tag-outline"
             ng-repeat="tag in ::$ctrl.article.tagList">
             {{ tag }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
<hr />
<div class="article-actions">
  <article-actions article="$ctrl.article"></article-actions>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <div>
      <form class="card comment-form">
        <div class="card-block">
          <textarea class="form-control"
            placeholder="Write a comment..."
            rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <img class="comment-author-img" />
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">
               Post Comment
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
            <p class="card-text">This is an example comment.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <a class="comment-author" href="">
              <img class="comment-author-img" />
            </a>
            &nbsp;
            <a class="comment-author" href="">
              BradGreen
            </a>
            <span class="date-posted">
              Jan 20, 2016
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, your example will work with angular 1.5 but not >1.6.

here is the reason :

Starting with angular 1.6, bindings are not yet set in the constructor. If you need them, move your code to the `$onInit` function.

Here is your new ArticleActionsCtrl :

```
class ArticleActionsCtrl {
  constructor(Articles, User, $state) {
    'ngInject';

    this._Articles = Articles;
    this._$state = $state;
    this.User = User;
  }

  $onInit() {    
     if (this.User.current) {
       this.canModify = (this.User.current.username === this.article.author.username);
     } else {
       this.canModify = false;
     }
  }
}

let ArticleActions = {
  bindings: {
    article: '='
  },
  controller: ArticleActionsCtrl,
  templateUrl: 'article/article-actions.html'
};

export default ArticleActions;
```

I did not test it, do not hesitate to tell me if you have any problem with it.

Comment: That was absolutely it! Thank you for the explanation and code example. Just to help myself debug issues like that myself, did you just know this over time from coding or should i have been able to find this change documented regarding constructor/onInit issue in the angular documentation

Comment: I had a similar issue when upgrading from angular 1.5 to 1.6. No magic trick here :)